# I have integrated kcfinder with config.js file but still browse server option not visible

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, kcfinder

I have integrated *kcfinder* with **config.js** but the browse server button is not visible.

i am using xampp server and my host file structure as per below

> **xampp -> htdocs -> ckeditor_test -> admin -> index.php**
>
> **xampp -> htdocs -> ckeditor_test -> ckeditor -> config.js**
>
> **xampp -> htdocs -> ckeditor_test -> kcfinder**

And my index.php code & confing.js integrated code is as below.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="editor" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
</body>
```

**config.js**

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
// ...
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
// ...
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear your browser cache.
Also, since your `index.php` is inside `admin` folder, you need to go up a folder for `kcfinder` like this:

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
// ...
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '../kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '../kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '../kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '../kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
// ...
};
```